# How can I do to execute some functions using Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Hello I have a Django project but I can't achieve to execute some functions. I precise I have a file in my app by the name of file2.py and I tried this :

```
import file2
```

And I got this :

```
No module named 'file2'
```

Could you help me please ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show me your file/directory structure?

Comment: Actually I try to execute `os.listdir()` but I realize I have to go to a folder in which there the file2.py.

Answer (score 1):

If you have this file in the same directory, you can access it's functions like this:
`from .file2 import function`

The dot is important, since it clarifies the path to the file

For example: you have defined some `foo_form` in your `forms.py` and you want to use it in your `views.py`, which is in the same directory as `forms.py`, your `views.py` should look like this:

```py
from .forms import foo_form

def foo(request):

    form = foo_form()
```

If the file you want to import is in different directory though, you may want to check this question: [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
from .file2 import *
```

Can u post more information, such as the folder structure

Comment: I got `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import` :/

Comment: It is because it is trying the relative path, this file is in the same directory?

Comment: No I have to go to the following directory folder1